# Meaning of 'inputEV'

Tags: ios, image, cifilter

What is the meaning of the key name 'inputEV' which is used in the CIFilter 'CIExposureAdjust'?

For example :

```
    CIFilter *exposureFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIExposureAdjust"];
    [exposureFilter setValue:outputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [exposureFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:5] forKey:@"inputEV"];
    CIImage *outputImage = [exposureFilter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the exposure value, as per the documentation:

> This filter multiplies the color values, as follows, to simulate
>   exposure change by the specified F-stops:
>
> `s.rgb * pow(2.0, ev)`